# Wordpress theme wp_nav_menu

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with my theme. I start to learn wordpress theme designer and try to base my theme on bootstrap 4.

Okey, my html code view like bootstrap examples:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But in wp when I using this code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'menu' => 'Teamwant',
  'theme_location'    => 'primary',
  'container'           => 'ul',
  'container_class'     => 'nav nav-pills',
  'container_id'        => '',
  'menu_class'          => 'nav nav-pills',
  'menu_id'             => '',
  'echo'                => true,
  'fallback_cb'         => 'wp_page_menu',
  'before'              => '',
  'after'               => '',
  'link_before'         => '',
  'link_after'          => '',
  'items_wrap'          => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
  'depth'               => 0,
  'walker'              => ''
  );
wp_nav_menu( $args );

 ?>
```

My theme not display block. I can't run drop down menu etc.
Primary problem it is

```
<li>
```

class.

How I can change it's ?

And how I can create drop down menu ?

And how I can set active class for active item (when I open link from menu) ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: I believe you are going to need a walker class for your dropdown menus to work. https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Comment: When I set walker' => 'active' menu not show

Comment: You need to set 'walker' => 'new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()' and include the walker class file from that github repository in your theme.

Comment: Okey, now work fine, but how I make drop down list ?